# Linked Objects Lose Linkage

Tags: c#, winforms, automapper

Well, i have kinda strange question but i will try my best to illustrate it as i spent the last couple of days trying to find a solution but failed.

In my application i have a windows form that contains many tile like controls that display the `Employee's` data. since the beginning of my app development i have used a strange way to keep the UI updated to any changes to the `Employee` Entity which i will demonstrate in the code below.

```
Company company = new Company();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    company.Name = "Company Name";
    company.Employees = employees;

    this.Controls.Add(new EmployeeTile {Tag = company.employees[0]}); //I tag every tile with an employee from the array.
    this.Controls.Add(new EmployeeTile {Tag = company.employees[1]}); //I tag every tile with an employee from the array.
    this.Controls.Add(new EmployeeTile {Tag = company.employees[2]}); //I tag every tile with an employee from the array.
    this.Controls.Add(new EmployeeTile {Tag = company.employees[3]}); //I tag every tile with an employee from the array.
    //Then at the Employee Tile i have a timer which runs every couple of seconds and updates it self from the Tag object.
    //If any change made to the corresponding employee in the array it will be applied to the Tag of the Tile too.
}
```

And that way worked fine until i used auto mapper to automatically apply the changes to the Employees

```
var comp = new Company()
{
    Name = "Company Name",
    Employees = /*NEW EMPLOYEE ARRAY WITH THE SAME COUNT AND EVERY THING BUT UPDATED VALUES*/
}
Mapper.Map<Company, Company>(/*FROM THE COMPANY OBJECT I NEWELY CREATED*/ comp, company /*TO THE EXISTING ONE*/);
```

Once I do that the ui no longer updates as if somehow the linkage between the `Tag` and it's corresponding array member no longer exists. Although this overload of automapper should not create new object and just copies values to the existing one.

EmployeeTileControl

```
public EmployeeTile()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //TIME USING REACTIVE EXTENSIONS.
    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), new ControlScheduler(this)).Subscribe(_ =>
    {
        Employee employee = Tag as Employee;
        if (null != employee)
        {
            this.lblEmployeeName.Text = string.Format("Name: {0}", employee.Name);
            this.lblEmployeeAge.Text = string.Format("Age: {0}", employee.Age);
        }
        //SO IT KEEPS UPDATING THE UI EVERY 1 SECOND WITH THE INFO FROM THE TAG.
        //AS IT SUPPOSED THAT THIS TAG IS REFLECTING THE `ORIGINAL` EMPLOYEE INSTANCE FROM THE ARRAY.
        //SO IT MUST BE UPDATED WHEN EVERY THE ORIGINAL INSTANCE IS UPDATED.
    });
}
```

NB: I am a pretty new programmer so i might referred to something in the wrong terms, and i hope you correct me. Also the title might be very wrong but i don't know what else should i call it.

Comment: Why are you adding the `Employee` to the Tag? `EmployeeTile` is your class right? Have you considered adding a constructor to `EmployeeTitle` that takes in an `Employee`? E.g. `EmployeeTile(Employee employee)`

Comment: @ianO'Brien EmployeeTile is my control

Comment: i tag it with the Employee so it keeps track of it and updates it self with a timer from it.

Comment: as it supposed that when you `=` 2 objects they become the same and when you commit changes to one of them the other gets affected.

Comment: "Although this overload of automapper should not create new object and just copies values to the existing one." Have you verified this by debugging? In the debugger, you can check to see if AutoMapper is creating new instances, or even proxies.

Comment: @JesseWebb i have printed the Object Hash of the object before and after automapping and they are the same

Comment: It would be helpful to see your `EmployeeTile` class. I understand though if you don't want to share all the details of it, but could you at least show us a trimmed-down version with all the references to its `Tag` property?

Comment: Ofcourse. i will update my question now

Comment: @RuneS Sorry, no luck yet. To be honest though, don't hold your breath for a solution from me specifically; I am interested in this problem but it is low on my priority list of stuff to do. I will let you know if I figure anything out though. ;)

Comment: @JesseWebb: oh i am so sorry for bothering you dude. Thanks a lot from your attention.